# Calculating the remaining loan balance

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C to calculate the remaining loan balance after a given number of months, given the balance, monthly payment amount, and interest rate. (Each month, the balance increases by (balance * (interest rate/12)), and decreases by the payment amount.)

My code to calculate the balance for each month is as follows:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    loanAmount += (loanAmount * (intRate/12));
    loanAmount -= monthlyPayment;
    printf("The balance after month %d is %.2f\n", i, loanAmount);
}
```

I put in some values (`loanAmount = 1000`, `intRate = 12`, `monthlyPayment = 100`, `n = 3`), and I expected the result to be 910.00 after month 1, 819.10 after month 2, and 727.29 after month 3. However, I got these results instead:

```
Enter the loan amount:
1000
Enter the interest rate:
12
Enter the monthly payment amount:
100
Enter the number of monthly payments:
3
The balance after month 1 is 1900.00
The balance after month 2 is 3700.00
The balance after month 1 is 7300.00
```

What am I doing wrong in my code? I thought my algorithm was correct.

Comment: Please do not include images - actual code is better since (we) I can cut&paste it to test it

Comment: You may want to use some floating point numbers and divide that interest rate by 100 first =P

Comment: Sorry about the images, I'm working in a remote terminal and don't know how to copy/paste.

Comment: Putty will let you for example

Comment: ...I can't believe I forgot to divide by 100. It's a percentage, of course. Thank you!

Comment: No kidding. now *thats* doing the extra mile on a q-edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interest rate needs to be .12 as your are just multiplying by 1 at the moment, therefore adding 1000 to the balance and then subtracting the payment.

Comment: Thank you! My bad, I guess I just failed to see such an elementary mistake. Time to get some sleep, I think...

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another(or a few) sets of eyes.  :P